# Undefined variable template_2 laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Getting error with following code

```
$result = User::where("device_token", "!=", "")->where("device_type", "!=", "")->get();
        $template_2 = DB::table('notification_templates')->get();
return view('admin.push_notifications')
        ->withPage('push_notifications')
        ->with([
                'result' => $result,
                'template_2' => $template_2,
            ]);
```

view:

```
 @if(($template_2))
    @foreach($template_2 as $taken)

     {{ $taken->title }

       @endforeach
   @endif
```

PHP v5.5.9

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: Undefined variable template_2

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam see my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to your question your code must work.. If not works you can try this code:-

```
$result = User::where("device_token", "!=", "")->where("device_type", "!=", "")->get();
$template = DB::table('notification_templates')->get();
return view('admin.push_notifications')->with(compact('result','template'));
```

View should be:-

```
@if(isset($template))
  @foreach($template as $taken)

 {{ $taken->title }

   @endforeach
@endif
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Undefined variable template_2

Comment: but i am using only $template not $template_2 please see my answer carefully

Comment: have you tried my code or you doing guesses @MuhammadMuazzam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159665/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-kunal).